# Изменить внешний вид Android эмулятора

Tags: android, эмулятор

Никак не могу разобраться, **как убрать эти кнопки сбоку**? В настройках не нахожу нужный пункт.

[image: Эмулятор]

Comment: это какой то древний эмулятор..в новой студии такого нет

Answer (score 2):

```
Edit Android Virtual Device -> Skin -> Resolution
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проставляете нужные размеры и эмулятор скроет клавиатуру

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007190/how-to-show-the-android-emulator-without-a-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Вид эмулятора изменить нельзя.

Всё что можно сделать,это скачать другой эмулятор.

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com).

Он хорош своей простотой и легкостью в загрузке, и не так сильно загружает систему,как это делает стандартный эмулятор Android Studio.

Есть бесплатная версия.

P.S. И вид там красивый)

Comment: Не знаю как сейчас обстоят дела, но раньше, на мой взгляд, BlueStacks и быстрее был, и проще, и красивее, чем Genymotion

Comment: @Regent никогда не пользовался им,поэтому не знаю

Comment: сейчас в студии хороший эмулятор..зачем эти дженимоушены

Comment: @Cypher на вкус и цвет товарища нет